# Wrong caption using 'Appendix' header style

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I am using following style for numbering Appendixes. But when i add caption to the figure or table numbering starts from 0, not A as I expect. For example:

```
Figure 0.1 instead Figure A.1
```

What am I doing wrong?

[image: Numbering format]

Answer (score 2):

If what I say here is wrong, you should use Alt-F9 to reveal the field codes that generate the Caption number and tell us what they are. Here, for example, Word inserts

Figure { STYLEREF 1 \s }-{ SEQ Figure \* Arabic as 1 }

The STYLEREF field in this example picks up the numbering of the previous paragraph with style "Heading 1" (or, if it's before the first such paragraph, it will probably pick up the numbering of the first such paragraph).

Normally, when you try to insert a caption, Word prevents you from doing so if there are no paragraphs with the style you selected (and the style has to be one of the 9 standard Heading styles), or if the style exists but is not numbered using Outline/Multilevel numbering.

If you already have captions in your text that have been inserted using Chapter-item numbering, and you have some paragraphs with the right Heading n (say Heading 1) style, then { STYLEREF 1 \s } will display "0". Which is probably what is happening.

So what you need to do is ensure that the paragraphs you are using to provide the first part of the number are

a. Heading style paragraphs (Heading 1, etc, or they may be called something different if you are not using an English language version of Word)

b. Numbered using the Multilevel numbering box (you are using the "ordinary" numbering tab). Within that, you need to select an option that shows the "Heading" styles, or create your own numbering and ensure that you associate a Heading style with the level you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The heading 1 style seems to need to be part of the numbering to work.

For instance,

1. Introduction (where the 1. comes from the Heading-1-style-format with numbering applied and Introduction is what I typed) gave me Figure 1.1 but when I deleted the "1." from the introduction part so that it looked the way I wanted it, it changed to Figure 0.1 after I updated the field even though it was still nominally a Heading 1 style.

So I went back and applied the heading style to show "1. Introduction", then selected the "1." in introduction, and went to font and clicked hidden to make it not show up in the printing.