# Can I control Caption sequence numbering from styles other than "Heading "?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, numbering, field-codes

Similar question to [Wrong caption using 'Appendix' header style](https://superuser.com/questions/645647/wrong-caption-using-appendix-header-style) , so the answer may well be "I can't."
I created a style called "Appendix" which is based on "Heading 1" , is at "level 1" , and is numbered A,B,C... .

I use the standard "Insert Caption" to get Figure or Table captions. I then modded the first field code to be `STYLEREF "Appendix" \s` and that properly displays the Appendix letter sequence.  However, the second field code, `SEQ \s 1` refers to the last "Heading 1" . I've tried things like `SEQ \s "Appendix"` to no avail.
Is there any way around this?  Should I generate a new "Appendix caption"-ish style which is a "numbered list" and manually set the 'restart at 1' counting in each Appendix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A tentative answer:  I inserted a `Heading 9` line just below each `Appendix` heading and set the `heading 9` to Hidden Text.  Then I could set the captions' sequence switch to `\s 9` . The captions number sequences are proper and the hidden-text headings are not captured in the Table of Contents.

Edit - it hardly seems worth going this route, as I might just as well hack the definition of `Heading 9` directly to count by  "A,B,C" and have font style similar to  `Heading 1` in the first place.  You'd think Microsoft could come up with a more flexible way to define nonstandard chapter headings.

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the SEQ numbering explicitly and invisibly using (example pertains to a Figure)

```
{ SEQ Figure \r0 \h }
```

Try putting one of those (for each sequence you need) in each Appendix heading.

Comment: I'll give that a shot, but it may be more trouble than it's worth.  Thanks for pointing this out.